# FreeType 2 macro FT_FREETYPE_H error C1083

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, macros, freetype2

I have downloaded and installed from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/freetype.php

Added include C:\Program Files %28x86%29\GnuWin32\include
and lib C:\Program Files %28x86%29\GnuWin32\lib
paths in Visual Studio under VC++ Directories

Added freetype.lib in Linker-Input in Additional Dependencies

Following tutorial on http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html
I have added in my code

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
```

But I get

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'freetype/config/ftheader.h': No such file or directory

What is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You probably missed to specify the additional include path for this library in your project settings.

Comment: In C/C++ - General? What should I put there?

Comment: I have followed this tutorial: http://beeproc.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/building-static-freetype2-with-msvc-2012/ and it works now!